# Find projection of vector $v$ on $w$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

One of my textbooks reports that to find the length of a projection of $v$ on $w$ I need to use the following formula:

$$\frac{\langle v, w\rangle}{||w||}$$

My professor told us the formula to find the vector of the projection is

$$p_w(v)= \frac{\langle v, w\rangle}{\langle w, w\rangle}\cdot w$$

Now, in the first we should be getting a number, in the second we should be getting a vector. I don't understand how someone could rework these formulas to get one from the other. Any hints?

Comment: The first formula is wrong.

Comment: It'd be $||w||^2$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first formula is the **signed length** (i.e. the length, if the projection is pointing in the same direction as $w$, or the length, multiplied by $-1$, if the direction is reversed) of the vector in the second formula, since (using the simple fact that $\langle w,w\rangle = \|w\|^2$)

$$\frac{\langle v,w\rangle}{\langle w,w\rangle}\cdot w = \frac{\langle v,w\rangle}{\|w\|^2}\cdot w = \frac{\langle v,w\rangle}{\|w\|}\cdot \frac{w}{\|w\|}$$

and, of course, the length of the vector $\frac{w}{\|w\|}$ is $1$.

Comment: Absolute value signs missing in the question and this answer. Length of the projection has to be positive.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy you are correct.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how you go from the second passage, where you multiply the fraction by the vector $w$ to the third passage. Also, I'm not sure if my first formula in my question is correct.

Comment: @Cesare Well, the first formula is not the same as the second. The first formula is just a definition, so it cannot be incorrect - it's only incorrect in conjunction with the second formula, which is a contradicting definition. Indeed, the second formula is the standard definition of a projection. But if you just want the length (and direction) of the projection, the first formula is what you need.

Comment: @Cesare I for from one to the other using the fact that $$\|w^2\| = \|w\|\cdot\|w\|$$ and the fact that $$\frac{a}{b\cdot c} = \frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{1}{c}$$